# Index performance with a startswith structure

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

Is there not an expression in neo4j like startswith that runs fast on an indexed property?

I currently run a query like

```
match (p:Page) where p.Url =~ 'http://www.([\\w.?=#/&]*)' return p
```

The p.Url property is indexed however the query above is very slow. Especially a startswith index search should be quite fast or not?

Answer (score 0):

Currently regex (or 'startsWith') filters are not supported with schema indexes. Your cypher statement will scan through all nodes having the `Page` label and filter them based on their properties.

More sophisticated query capabilities for schema indexes are to be expected in one of the next releases of Neo4j.

If you need that functionality now you basically have 2 options:

1. use legacy indexes as documented in the [reference manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html).
2. if your queries always filter for starting with `protocoll://prefix` you can work around by putting the prefix `protocoll://prefix` into an additional property `urlPrefix` and declare an index on it (`create index on :Page(urlPrefix)`. Your query is then `match (p:Page) where p.urlPrefix='http://www.' return p` and will be run via the existing index.

Comment: Another option is to use something external like elasticsearch.